# mongoexport command doesn't output valid json

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongo-shell

I used mongoexport to export a collection but the output doesn't seem to be valid JSON.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"631b037aeab483da36b1773c"},"name":"A","age":32,"city":"AB"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"631b03b6eab483da36b1773d"},"name":"B","age":33,"city":"ABB"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"631b03ffeab483da36b1773e"},"name":"C","age":34,"city":"AABB"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"631b040beab483da36b1773f"},"name":"D","age":35,"city":"AAABBB"}
```

Don't the above documents need to be in an `array` separated by commas to be valid JSON? And when I try to import valid json it doesn't seem to work unless it uses the above format.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use the [`--jsonArray`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/#std-option-mongoexport.--jsonArray) option? `mongoimport` has a parallel [option](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/#std-option-mongoimport.--jsonArray).

Comment: The format is NDJSON: http://ndjson.org/